# Angular $http.get and variable use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, angularjs

Ok, so still new to Angular, using 1.3.1, and here's my problem:

```
console.log('CompanyID: ' + $scope.companyID);

$http.get('/api/List/GetGangTemplates', { params: { id:$scope.companyID }})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('CompanyID SUCCESS: ' + $scope.companyID);
        $scope.templates.data = data;
    })
```

first console.log -> 'CompanyID: undefined'

second console.log (in success) -> 'CompanyID SUCCESS: 1' // this is what it should be!

Looking at my Scope via batarang shows companyID: 1.

I should note that this is a MVC / Angular hybrid.  My Razor page has the following:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.CompanyID, New With {.ng_init = "companyID=" & Model.CompanyID})
```

What am I missing? I want to use a hidden field on my Razor page to pass an ID to Angular to do my AJAX call....

Comment: Just to make this more fun - did a console.log($scope) on the line immediately before this code block - I can clearly see companyID: 1!  So why on the very next line is $scope.companyID undefined?

Comment: The scope will be the object post digest,  while an element of it may have yet to compile.  Just set the value in the controller, or put a timeout of 0 to push it a step later.

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  Looks like a $scope.$evalAsync($http.get in here) did the trick.  I think you're right - timing issue :)  Thanks!

Comment: How are you assigning '$scope.companyID' . Is it being assigned in the controller?

Comment: Luke, I was assigning via the .ng_init in the Razor page shown above